# What's a Good Soil Quality Index for Plowed Farm Lands?

Tags: soil, agriculture, satellites, soil-moisture, soil-science

I'm currently conducting research using Satellite/Weather/Soil (Mostly Sentinel-2 Satellite Imagery) Data to Model Smallholder Farms and their dynamics before Planting.

Key to my progress is to find a way to Assess the quality of farmlands soil right after Ploughing based on the available data. I was looking for either remote sensing-based or Soil-based indices that quantify the Quality of plowed lands.

Are there any such indices that I can infer using Sentinel/Landsat-based Imagery or Soil/Weather properties?

Comment: Soil moisture is measurable remotely, but soil quality?

Comment: this is realy not my field but you can use the type of plants growing in an area to estimate soil quality,satelites can find the type of plants growing in an area by analyzing the spectra.i think you can get some data for this at the agricultural department where you live.

Comment: @Erik Yes, we can measure soil moisture remotely, but can we consider it the sole factor in assessing plowed land quality? Initially, I decided on measuring Vegetation Quality in General, But when you think about it, a plowed land shouldn't have a good vegetation index (Like NDVI) Because it was plowed. Another Idea that I'm not sure about is to consider quality as a measure of change between Before/After Plowing States, the bigger the change, the better the plowing, but I'm not sure this would work since change can come from many phenomena. What do you think?

Comment: @trondhansen I'm interested in Modeling Farming in Nigeria, So I think it'll take a lot of effort to have any data from the agricultural department, & that is why I'm relying, for the most part, on satellite imagery & weather.

Comment: Ok, now you are confusing me. Do you need an index for soil quality, do you want to classify soil quality based on remote sensing data, or do you want to determine the quality of the plowing?

Comment: @Erik Sorry for the confusion. Say in a certain date T we have a Sentinel-2 Image of an already plowed farm, I want to Convert that Image into a number that gives an estimation of that land Vegetation quality after plowing. In simple terms, How good was the plowing we see in the Image.

Comment: Please [edit](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/posts/17368/edit) your question accordingly to clarify this issues, thank you.